# python list seemingly randomly disappearing

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, module

I have made a script to test run times of different sorting algorithms I wrote. the code is here:

```
import random
import sort
import time

print ('test sort functions for integer lists')
integers = [random.randint(1,999) for n in range(1, random.randint(1000,2000)) ]
print('ordering', len(integers), 'ints')

print('start selection sort')
ts=time.clock()
print(sort.selection(integers))
print ('end selection sort with time', time.clock()-ts, '\n')


print('start merge sort')
tm=time.clock()
print(sort.merge(integers))
print ('end merge sort with time', time.clock()-tm, '\n')
```

When calling the function `sort.merge(integers)`, an empty list is passed to it for some reason. I tested this by placing `print(integers)` there instead, but to my knowledge should be exactly the same list as passed to `sort.selection(integers)`. Anybody got an idea what's going on?

---

contents of my sort.py module:

```
import math

def merge(ints):
    if (len(ints) < 2):
        return (ints)
    else:
        print('recursion')
        i=merge(ints[0:math.ceil(len(ints)/2)]) #calls recursive function for
        j=merge(ints[math.ceil(len(ints)/2):])  #both halves of list
        k=[] #beginning of merge algorithm
        ic=0
        jc=0
        while (ic < len(i) and jc < len(j)):   #repeat as long as end of i
            if (i[ic] < j[jc]): #append lowest value to k
                k.append(i[ic])
                ic+=1 #track which values of i are accounted for
                if (ic == len(i)): #if i is exhausted
                    for a in range (jc, len(j)): #fill k with j
                        k.append(j[jc])
                        jc+=1
                    break
            if (i[ic] >= j[jc]):
                k.append(j[jc])
                jc+=1
                if (jc == len(j)):
                    for a in range (ic, len(i)):
                        k.append(i[ic])
                        ic+=1
                    break
        return (k) 

def selection(ints,order='a'):
    maxint=0
    orderedints=[]
    if (order == 'desc' or order == 'descending' or order == 'd'):
        while (len(ints) > 0):
            maxint=maxof(ints)
            ints.remove(maxint)
            orderedints.append(maxint)
        return (orderedints)

    if (order == 'asc' or order == 'ascending' or order == 'a'):
        while (len(ints) > 0):
            minint=maxof(ints)
            for i in range (0, len(ints)):
                if (ints[i] < minint):
                    minint = ints[i]
            ints.remove(minint)
            orderedints.append(minint)
        return (orderedints)

def maxof(a):
    maxint=0
    for i in range (0, len(a)):
        if (a[i] > maxint):
            maxint = a[i]
    return (maxint)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `sort.selection` is modifying the list is passed in, like so:

```
ints.remove(maxint)
```

If you want to operate on a local copy of the list, add:

```
ints = ints[:]
```

early in your `sort.selection()` routine.

Comment: So when I pass a list to a function, it doesn't duplicate that list, but just work with the list that's referenced?

Answer (score 1):

Inside `sort.selection`, you are calling `ints.remove`. Since `ints` is just another reference to the list referenced by `integers` (*not* a copy), a side effect of `sort.selection` is to empty the input list while returning a sorted copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `sort.selection` removes values from the list it gets as its argument.  Since it returns the new list, you need to assign that list back to your variable.

Change this part:

```
print(sort.selection(integers))
```

to:

```
integers = sort.selection(integers)
print(integers)
```

Comment: The OP needs the same unsorted list, otherwise (s)he would be sorting already sorted lists in the other tests.